# Mocha tests in node.js hanging or missing

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

At the moment I am working on a project for which I am supposed to write the routing using express.js in node.js.

The tests and the other parts of the project were not written by me, therefore I assume there is no error in them.

The problem I am having is: At the current stage of the program when I run "npm test" I get the tests hanging and control doesn't get back to the command line. I have noticed that when I comment out all the lines in server.js, api.js and employees.js the tests run smoothly.

Plus, sometimes only a part of the tests is executed, like 1/3 of them.

Any idea why are the tests hanging, and how to fix them?

Here is the package.json file plus the main files of the project so far.

Thanks in advance.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "expresso",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "errorhandler": "^1.5.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mocha": "^6.1.4",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "sqlite3": "^4.0.6",
    "supertest": "^3.0.0",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^2.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^3.5.5"
  }
}
```

**server.js**

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const errorHandler = require('errorhandler');
const express = require('express');
const apiRouter = require('./api/api');

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

app.use('/api', apiRouter);

app.use(errorHandler());

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`);
});

module.exports = app;
```

**api.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const apiRouter = express.Router();
const employeesRouter = require('./employees');

    // <<< api/employees >>>
apiRouter.use('/employees', employeesRouter);

module.exports = apiRouter;
```

**employees.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const employeesRouter = express.Router();

const sqlite = require('sqlite3');
const db = new sqlite.Database('./database.sqlite');

    // <<< api/employees >>>
employeesRouter.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    const sql = 'SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE is_current_employee = 1';

    db.all(sql, (error, employees) => {
        if (error) {
            next(error);
        } else {
            res.status(200).json({ employees: employees });
        }
    });

});


module.exports = employeesRouter;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add the tag `--exit` in `scripts -> test` into your `package.json`.

The result should be something like:

```json
"scripts": {
  "test": "mocha --exit"
}
```

According to [docs](https://mochajs.org/#command-line-usage)

> --exit : Force Mocha to quit after tests complete

After that, when tests finish, command line is available again.

Comment: Thanks to much! This allows the tests to run and return control to the console!

Still, unfortunately, at the current stage of the project only 30 of the 80+ total tests are performed.

Do you have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: I think that issue could be a problem with tests implementation. Does the console output a message when tests fails?

Comment: I think I get some unusual error. Here is the detailed result -> https://codepen.io/Newvolante5/pen/poEzxJo?editors=0010.

Comment: That's a problem with tests implementation. Assertions are not correct in most of them. Maybe test is bad written or maybe the app is failling and tests are ok. You have to talk to who wrote the tests. But this is another question I think.

Comment: saved my day. thx